# Which register has 'this' pointer in assembly language? (Rever Engineering)

Tags: macos, assembly

In Mac OS, that looks like the EDI stored the handle of current instance of one class. Is it right? I hope to call other class methods via it.

Even though I checked Intel 64bit manual and AMD64 ABI interface, there is no clear answer about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would usually be in RDI, as it's treated as the first parameter to a function, and under the ABI, that parameter is passed in RDI.

caveat: If the return value from the method is non-trivial (i.e. it's a temporary allocated in stack) then there is an additional 1st parameter passed, which is the address of that temporary, and which comes before the `this` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the definition in below document:
  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECSOMEASSEMBLY

Thanks!